What’s the best way to measure `ConstantSourceNode`’s offset?
Let’s say, ConstantSourceNode’s current offset value is needed in the main thread: for the purposes of visualization, or for the purposes of launching audio nodes, etc.
There can be many such nodes.
It’s known that offset.value does not reflect current changes. What is better?

Initialize an AnalyserNode (and the whole shebang, including Float32Array to collect data and potentially BiquadFilterNode to avoid noise), attach it to every ConstantSourceNode needing measurement, and call getFloatTimeDomainData() when needed.
Define a worklet and gather measurements with a message. I guess one benefit is that it can push changes with postMessage(), as opposed to only being able to poll them with the analyser.

The important factors are:

Precision in time. Say, for the purposes of launching or seeking an audio node, it’s desirable to know exactly when value changed. I’d say ideally down to a sample, however, it’s unclear whether main thread’s involvement will make such precision useless.
Resource usage, of course (memory and compute).

